# Test flight SDK Updated but deprecated in ios

Tags: ios, testflight

I had using TestFlight SDK 2.0 before,After that I had download TestFlight SDK 2.2.1 and replace the all files, integrated in my App.And removes the old files also.
But I'm facing a problem while uploading latest build to TestFlight.
Still The SDK is showing 2.0 and deprecated.
Please suggest me to resolve this. [image: Scree shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The odds are pretty good the old one is still around somewhere in your project.

Once trick that I've used before to find out if something is still in the project somewhere is to open the project file with a text editor. (BareBones Softeware's BBEdit is great, but their freeware Text Wrangler will also work just fine for this.)

Once it is open just search for the "bad" file and search the entire project. You might find it there and that will help you track it down. You can *edit* this file but be careful, it is XML and it had better still be valid XML when you save it.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem where I updated the SDK, but the old SDK was still showing up in TestFlight.  Turns out I had to go into Build Settings --> Search Paths --> Library Search Paths and sure enough, this was still pointing to the old SDK folder.  I just updated this to the new folder.